# Android Studio - Debugging works in main activity but not others

Tags: debugging, android-studio, breakpoints

I have an app that I've just ported from Eclipse to Android Studio.  I've got debugging breakpoints being hit in the main activity.  But if I invoke a subsidiary activity (via startActivityForResult), that activity runs but breakpoints in its code aren't hit.

I'm on Android Studio 1.0.2.

Update

My fault I'm afraid.  But the situation may be of interest to others migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio.

When setting up the build.gradle file, I inadvertently put an upper case "W" in my applicationId thus: 'com.pcdbdev.pcdbWaypoints'.  There was no such "W" under Eclipse.  So when Android Studio started the app, either it or Android treated it as a separate package and kept both the new apk file and the last one I uploaded under Eclipse.  So I could debug my main activity OK.  But when I started another Activity from it, the activity invoked was from the old (undebugable) apk.  This led to other problems, such as inability to pass an Intent or SharedPreferences between the two activities.

Editing the build.gradle file to make the id 'com.pcdbdev.pcdbwaypoints' made the problem go away.